# using PopUpManager in a Flex 4.5 Mobile App

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile

This is more of a best practices question rater than something technical.

I'm working on a mobile app using the Flex 4.5 SDK and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle notification windows. In most cases these windows will be alerting the user to when something goes wrong. Ex: bad login, no data, cannot resolve server.

I'm using a singleton design pattern, I have a Requests class that handles server calls. Most popups will be originating from this class (IOErrorEvents from my loader being used to access the API). Since this class is a singleton and is used from all Views inside the app it is not aware of applications current view. I'm also not sure having this class keep track of the current view and having it push popups on top of it would be best practice.

I'm hoping that I can use PopUpManager to keep track of where to add popups and what popups are currently on the stage. Though all examples I've seen online about this show static Components being used in a views Declarations tag.

I'm really just looking for any examples or input on how you would solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and sorted it by making an Alert popup component that you can call from anywhere in the code base, and it will pop up in the currently active window. It also has an always visible scrollbar text area which is handy

http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=502

It works for a view navigator application, but if your using a tabbed navigator application, you can add a call for that, or simply change the code to

```
mainTabbedNavigator = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator;
currentTab = mainTabbedNavigator.selectedNavigator as ViewNavigator;
```

Comment: Hey. I think a better option (in hindsight) may be to use a PopupContainer as the base of class of the AlertPopup, as it blurs out the background and looks a bit better. If you do so, give me a link to your update, cos I havnt done it yet:)